# Assigning Array Value to variable PHP

Tags: php

bit new to PHP I've been playing around a bit with it but I am unsure how to assign the string value of an array to a variable and print it. Currently it is only displaying the array number rather than it's data.

Any help/explanation appreciated

My current code is:

```
<?php

$family_friends = array();

array_push($family_friends, "James ");
array_push($family_friends, "Patrick");
array_push($family_friends, "Kevin");
array_push($family_friends, "Miles");
array_push($family_friends, "Reuben");

sort($family_friends);


// Randomly select a winner!

$winner = array_rand($family_friends, 1);

// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS

strtoupper($winner);


echo " ". "Congratulations"." ".($winner) . "!";

?>
```

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as reading the [manual](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) would have provided the answer.

Comment: @vascowhite - I didn't see that as one of the canned off-topic reasons :-)

Comment: @SeanBright That's the beauty of 'other'. You can make up your own :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`array_rand`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns a random *index*, not a random element.  You need to index into the array with its return value.  You also need to assign the result of `strtoupper` to a variable.  So:

```
strtoupper($winner);
```

Becomes:

```
$winner = strtoupper($family_friends[$winner]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`array_rand`returns an index, not an element. Therefore, you have to select the element of your array at the random index. Like this

```
strtoupper($family_friends[$winner]);
```

If `$winner` equals zero, `$family_friends[$winner]` equals "James".

Comment: Thanks for the help believe I understand this properly now had not realized it returned the index value, much appreciated.